# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find OpenHelperClass?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using the ormlite with sqlite. But we are getting the error are like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class class comactivty.ActivityName extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.  You should use getHelper(Context, Class) instead.
```

My code is:

```
public class DatabaseManager<H extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper> {

    private H helper;
    public H getHelper(Context context)
    {
        if(helper == null)
        {
            helper = (H) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context);
        }
        return helper;
    }

    public void releaseHelper(H helper)
    {
        if (helper != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.release();
            helper = null;
        }
    }

}
```

And this method `getHelper(context)`; is deprecated now so the error say use this `getHelper(Context, Class)`. So how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Do as the error message says, use method: `getHelper(Context, DatabaseManager.class);`